# In Unity, how do I create a drag and drop object?

Tags: unity, 2d

I have a 2d scene. I want the player to be able to pick up an object, move it around the scene and drop it somewhere. I can't find any way to do this, and all of the resources for Unity are really daunting and I can't find anything relevant to what I'm doing.

I've tried adding the drag rigidbody script to both my camera and the sprite I want to drag, to no effect.

Where can I find relevant documentation for stuff like this? Basic things like how to implement a script or what objects I need to attach these scripts to - the stuff on the unity website is a little too advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you say that the Object follows your mouse coordinates after you clicked it.

Use: 
`if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
            /*Move Object which gets hit by the Raycast you shoot to Mouse coordinates */};`

Also you have to convert the world coordinates to screen coordinates.

Here is a good Tutorial for that: [Klick](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eF8F5NHZoHQ)

Comment: Do I attach that script to the camera or each object I want to pick up? If it's the camera, how can I make it s.t. only one object can be dragged?

Comment: You can attach it to the camera or the a GameManager object.

Just shoot a [Raycast](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) and check with [RaycastHit](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit.html) for example the tag from the object you want to move